# Main Activity difference between VS2017 and VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Last night I migrated onto a new machine and had to install Visual Studio 2019, migrating all my projects over from my previous machine where I was using Visual Studio 2017.

Now for some reason why creating a Blank android app, I have a new method in my MainActivity.cs file.

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int 
    requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] 
    Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

When using VS2017, my MainActivity Class only contained one method:

```
protected override void OnCreate
```

I am struggling to work out if this has changed on VS2019 (not sure why that would matter), or if I have done something incorrect when installing and setting up the environment.

Any help would really be appreciated, as I am scrating my head over it.

Comment: Because FragmentActivity implements `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`, therefore your class would implement `OnRequestPermissionsResult`.... IMHO I am not sure what would have added that, it was added in 24.1.0, so if you changed the target to this or further then it would... Check the version you are targeting.

Comment: You upgraded right, who knows what happened TBH. What version are you targeting in your 2019 solution? `whycreating a Blank android app, I have a new method`, probably because it's targeting the current version...

Comment: Sorry was just doing some checking. Both were targeting Android Oreo 8.1 (so 27+ right)? My 2017 project won't even build in 2019. Getting a     "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly error.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ so I just installed VS2017 on my machine and it runs perfectly, so I am quite confused

Comment: You just installed VS2017, I thought it was VS2019 you *just* installed..?

Comment: I just installed VS2017 on my new machine to test if the projects still worked on it. Still have the issue on VS2019.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193534/discussion-between-james-pavett-and-codx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Xamarin wants to make you aware of Xamarin.Essentials.

Xamarin Essentials allows you to access platform depending features such as barometer, preferences, geocoding and so on over a defined API.

For all the supported feature have a look at the documentation. Be aware that some of the features are still in preview.

[Xamarin Essentials Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=windows%2Candroid)

As these feature are depending on permissions the library even request the permission and therefore xamarin.essentials has to be aware of the permission results.

[Permission Request Source Code](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/master/Xamarin.Essentials/Permissions/Permissions.android.cs)

Comment: That's just the answer I was looking for! Is there any way to have VS automatically update the Nuget package to v.1.1.0 for any new project. As right now I get quite a few errors that prevent the app from building until I update.

Comment: @JamesPavett The templates just take the files which where provided for the template. If the template does not build right away either there is a bug in the template or your visual studio setup is incorrect. With my visual studio 2019 the xamarin android projects works without any adjustment. Usually you don't want to update package version automatically in a project as this includes risks.